# Getting mariadb error while making back up of the database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to create a back up of my database in mariadb.
I'm using the following command to back up the database.

```
MariaDB [loginsys]> mysqldump loginsys > /home/username/Desktop/db.sql
```

I'm getting following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump loginsys loginsys > /home/shudarsan/Desktop/db.sql' at line 1

I also tried using:

```
MariaDB [loginsys]> mysqldump loginsys > db.sql;
```

It didn't work.

Is there anything wrong with the command?
My mariadb server version is:

> Server version: 10.5.9-MariaDB-1 Debian buildd-unstable

Comment: `mysqldump` is a console command, which you run in your bash/shell. It is not an SQL command you run in your `mysql` client.

Comment: I did run in mysql  console, not bash sell. It didn't work

Comment: Exactly, you shouldn't run it in the mysql console, it is not an SQL command or a command for the mysql client. You have to run it from the bash/shell you are using.

Comment: @ShudarsanRegmi: "shouldn't" means "should NOT"....

Comment: I got the following error:
when I ran mysqldump loginsys > db.sql
mysqldump: 9Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" when trying to connect)
when i ran from bash
and then I tried mysql -u dbusername -p mysqldump  loginsys > db.sql
I got some set of mysql help in db.sql(which was again an error for me)

Comment: @ShudarsanRegmi The `mysqldump` command also has parameters like `-u` and `-p` you can use to specify the login arguments. Run `mysqldump --help` to see the options available or check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-syntax.

Comment: @Progman Yeah, I tried passing some parameters like you mentioned and it did work. Thank you!!